# Python - How to returns a string in which each digit is replaced by the corresponding number of exclamation marks (!)

Tags: python

Hi I just started out coding and came across this question on my workbook:

Write a function (called excited_string) that takes a single string, s, as an argument and returns a string in which each digit is replaced by the corresponding number of exclamation marks (!).

What the code should do:

```
>>> excited_string("123")
'!!!!!!'
>>> excited_string(" 1 2 3 4 5")
' ! !! !!! !!!! !!!!!'
>>> excited_string("Wow1 This2 is1 super111 exci2ting")
'Wow! This!! is! super!!! exci!!ting'
>>> excited_string("Wow1 This2 is1 super111 exciting3")
'Wow! This!! is! super!!! exciting!!!'
```

My code so far:

```
def excited_string(s):
    new = ''
    for ch in s:
        if ch.isalpha() is False:
            print(int(ch) * '!')
```

Thanks for any guidance!

edit:
I got:

```
!
!!
!!!
```

then I got error for excited_string(" 1 2 3 4 5") due to the ' ' (spaces).

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.join() and a list comprehension

```
s = "1234"
for ch in s:
    if ch.isalpha() is False:
        print("".join("!" for i in range(int(ch))))
```

Outputs:

```
!
!!
!!!
!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when instructions mention "a function returns", you want to use the `return` syntax. The `return` syntax will end a function's execution and "give back" whoever called it the value written after `return`.

```py
def func1():
    x = 5
    return x

def gimme():
    the_value = func1()
    print(the_value)

gimme()
```

```
5
```

You started off well declaring `new` being a variable meant to hold the final value. And you were correct with the syntax `int(ch) * '!'`. Strings support the multiplication operator vs a number

```py
x = 'c' * 5
print(x)
```

```
ccccc
```

Now you just need to figure out how to concatenate each piece of string to the final result, in `new`, before `return`-ing it. Don't worry about anything fancy, try simple and straightforward first to exercise problem solving.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
result = ''.join( ['!'*int(c) if c.isdigit() else c for c in a] )
```

Testing:

```
>>> a = 'a2b5c2/'
>>> result = ''.join( ['!'*int(c) if c.isdigit() else c for c in a] )
>>> result
'a!!b!!!!!c!!/'
>>>
```